Difference between C and Rust in development Solana
I know C and Rust for Solana development. Difference between C and Rust in development Solana? When should we use C or Rust.

You should use C if you really need that last bit of performance that you can not achieve with rust.
But the documentation and examples for C are waaay less built out compared to rust. So I would recommend starting with rust.

can you tell me more about the last bit of performance. I never reach that
